# Aiohtpp RuntimeError: Event loop is closed

Tags: python, async-await, runtime-error, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I'm a beginer. This is the telegram bot code I am making for AWS Lambda. I get this error every time I wrap getting dp from my config in a function. And I tried both a regular function and an asynchronous one, it gives the same error. But the error disappears when I directly import the config from a global variable.

Also, the code below doesn't use asyncio.run() on purpose, because otherwise there was another thread-related error, only these three lines solved it.

```
import asyncio
from setting.setting import get_dp
from handlers.reg_hand import register_handlers
from aiogram import Bot, types, Dispatcher



async def process_event(event, dp):
    Bot.set_current(dp.bot)
    update = types.Update.to_object(event)
    await dp.process_update(update)


async def main(event):

    # here is that function
    dp = await get_dp()  
  
    await register_handlers(dp)
    await process_event(event, dp)
    
    return 'ok'


def lambda_handler(event):
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()   
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main(event))
```

Here is Traceback:

```
connections: ['[(<aiohttp.client_proto.ResponseHandler object at 0x7f96a406c520>, 5061.491615313)]']
connector: <aiohttp.connector.TCPConnector object at 0x7f96a407c4f0>
Unclosed connector
connections: ['[(<aiohttp.client_proto.ResponseHandler object at 0x7f96a4081e80>, 5067.667582065)]']
connector: <aiohttp.connector.TCPConnector object at 0x7f96a400f790>
Fatal error on SSL transport
protocol: <asyncio.sslproto.SSLProtocol object at 0x7f96a4070e80>
transport: <_SelectorSocketTransport closing fd=6>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 910, in write
    n = self._sock.send(data)
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/sslproto.py", line 685, in _process_write_backlog
    self._transport.write(chunk)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 916, in write
    self._fatal_error(exc, 'Fatal write error on socket transport')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 711, in _fatal_error
    self._force_close(exc)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 723, in _force_close
    self._loop.call_soon(self._call_connection_lost, exc)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 719, in call_soon
    self._check_closed()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 508, in _check_closed
    raise RuntimeError('Event loop is closed')
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
```

I tried wrapping the function in asyncio.gather(), I tried splitting main into multiple coroutines. But that doesn't solve the problem.

I also modified lambda_handler with different variations of asyncio.run() and added code from the forums.

I don't know. how to make it work.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: There are missing pieces, what is the definition of `get_dp` and other functions?

Comment: Function get_dp() just return dp

Comment: async def get_dp(): 
 bot = Bot(bot_token, parse_mode='HTML')
 dp = Dispatcher(bot)
 return dp

Comment: For convenience, there are two files in the settings folder: settings.py and config.py. If I do not use any functions there, not def not asynchronous def, then there is no error, but if I wrap the code in at least one of these files in at least one function, the above error appears.

Comment: I think this problem is not in the code at all, but in the operation of the asynchronous module, but I could be wrong

Answer (score 0):

This issue was related to the aiohttp session and resolved as follows:

```
async def main(event):
    dp = await get_dp()
    try:
        await register_handlers(dp)
        await process_event(event, dp)
    finally:
        s = await dp.bot.get_session()
        await s.close()
```

Comment: Click the check mark next to your answer to mark it as the solution.